# how to remove image background using opencv, android studio

Tags: java, android, opencv

I need to remove the background of an image using opencv but the code is not working please help

```
 private void processImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Mat rgba = new Mat();
        Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, rgba);
        if (rgba.empty()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to load image");
            return;
        }

        Mat mask = new Mat();
        Mat bgdModel = new Mat();
        Mat fgdModel = new Mat();
        Mat source = new Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(Imgproc.GC_PR_FGD));

        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, rgba.cols(), rgba.rows());

        Imgproc.grabCut(rgba, mask, rect, bgdModel, fgdModel, 5, Imgproc.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT);

        Core.compare(mask, source, mask, Core.CMP_EQ);

        Mat foreground = new Mat(rgba.size(), CvType.CV_8UC4, new Scalar(255, 255, 255, 255));
        rgba.copyTo(foreground, mask);

        Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(foreground.cols(), foreground.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(foreground, resultBitmap);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(resultBitmap);
    }
```

here is the error it says

> No implementation found for long org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat() (tried
> Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat and Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat__)
>
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 24253
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long
> org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat() (tried Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat and
> Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat__)

I tried different codes many times and also checked whether opencv was installed correctly using this code

```
if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
    Log.e(TAG, "OpenCV initialization failed.");
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV initialization succeeded.");
    openGallery();
}
```

opencv works